# document.<applet name>.isAlive() fails in some browsers

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have some java script to check if applet is finished loading before I load the rest of the page. It has worked for years, and now seems to be failing in Firefox 16 and IE 7. It works in IE 8

Any suggestions on why it has broken and what might fix it?

```
<applet name="env" archive="portal-applet-envir.jar" code="com/deleted/AppletEnvironment.class" height="1" mayscript="true" width="1">
</applet>
<table width="98%" align="center"><tr><td>
<script language="javascript">
function waituntilok() {
   if (document.env.isActive()) {
     doit();
  }
  else {
      var ct = 0;
      while (! document.env.isActive())
      {
      }
     doit();
   }
}
[....]
waituntilok();
</script>
</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: 1) By the looks of `waituntilok()` it would loop until `document.env.isActive()`.  Is it going into an infinite loop? 2) `code="com/deleted/AppletEnvironment.class"` should be `code="com.deleted.AppletEnvironment"`.

Comment: The loop does terminate when the applet finally loads.
The code parameter has been working until recently. Was I depending on a feature?

Comment: Don't know.  What is the result of `if (document)` & `if (document.env)`?  Pop an alert or write something to the page.  Should `name` be `id`?

Answer (score 1):

When `document.env.isActive()` is called before the applet is initialized, FF registers a 'no such method' error and quits the function.  It would pay to check the error console when debugging these things.

Also suspicious was the applet size of 1x1.  There are tools designed to protect the user that will remove HTML elements that are 'suspiciously small'.

This version works in FF.  Try it in both IE & FF and report back.

```
<html>
<body>
<applet
    name="env"
    archive="http://pscode.org/lib/mime.jar"
    code="org.pscode.mime.MimeType"
    height="100"
    mayscript="true"
    width="600">
</applet>
<table width="98%" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<script language="javascript">
function waituntilok() {
    if (document) {
        alert('document');
    }
    if (document.env) {
        alert('document.env');
    }
    if (document.env.isActive()) {
        doit();
    } else {
        var ct = 0;
        while (! document.env.isActive())
        {
        }
        doit();
    }
}

function doit() {
    alert('Just Do It!');
}

setTimeout('waituntilok()', 15000);
</script>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did see that no such method error in the log. I should have reported it.

Comment: the 1x1 size is intentional, I am using the applet to gather some information I use in a javascript function, but the user isn't supposed to see anything.

Comment: *"the 1x1 size is intentional"*  O_o  Tell me something that is ***not*** blatantly obvious.